# How to change the perspective of an image in Photoshop?

Tags: 3d, adobe-photoshop

I have a site screen shot(like this - http://d.pr/i/KxHN), and i want to rotate it to "perspective view" like the below image.

[image]

How i can do that? Google hinted nothing about this problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Follow this simple steps:

- Select the layer and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and
- Right click on the transform and choose Perspective and then
- Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag the right side corner towards down

[image]

Comment: On a Mac, you hold `alt` whilst dragging the corner transform handles.

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively to Bala's answer, If you're mocking your image on to something like a monitor for this example, I find it easier to use the `Distort` tool as you can drag the corners of the image to match what ever it is you're laying your image onto.

1. Edit → Transform → Distort
2. Drag the corner points to the edges of the monitor to fill the blank screen
3. Add a little inner shadow to the "mock screen" so it looks more "in place"

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With the image layer selected go to the toolbar at the top and select 'Edit → Transform → Perspective'.

It's also good practice to make your images "smart objects" before you edit them so they maintain their quality.

Right-click the image layer → Create smart object

This allows you to transform your image an infinite amount of times while still maintaining your image's original quality.

Hope this helps!